# AKKA Camel - how to unbox CamelMessage?

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I have the following simple route :

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder
import akka.actor.ActorRef

import akka.camel._

class SimpleRouteBuilder(val responder: ActorRef) extends RouteBuilder  {

  def configure =  {
    from("file:C:\\datafiles\\input?noop=true&readLock=changed").to(responder)
  }
```

My responder actor is the following :

```
class Responder extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => { ??? }
  }
}
```

Just wondering how do I cast msg of type CamelMessage to 
something useful so I can extract a file name or file path.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution , however as noted by Viktor Klang  it's error prone.

Change the route builder :

```
  from("file:C:\\datafiles\\input?noop=true&readLock=changed").convertBodyTo(classOf[java.io.File]).to(responder)
```

Unbox the java.io.File object in this way :

```
msg.body.asInstanceOf[java.io.File]
```

**CORRECT SOLUTION?**

A more correct solution seems to be :

```
implicit val camelContext = CamelExtension(context.system).context;

self ! camelMessage.bodyAs[java.io.File];
```

Comment: Hi, did you read the documentation? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/camel.html#Consumer_Actors and http://camel.apache.org/file.html ?

Comment: I did - this is not so much aI ran into problems when trying to call the msg.bodyAs function - it seems to require a "CamelContext" ...  but I discovered msg.body.asInstanceOf seems to be much easier, does not require a CamelContext ...anyways thanks !

Comment: Sadly you didn't read the documentation. It took me a couple of seconds to find this:  "You can access the CamelExtension inside a Producer or a Consumer using the camel definition, or get straight at the CamelContext using the camelContext definition. "

Comment: @ViktorKlang - look at my code - I'm not extending with Producer / Consumer :-)

Comment: @MadSab: But it shows in the docs how you obtain a reference to the CamelExtension given an ActorSystem, which you _do_ have access to: context.system

Comment: @ViktorKlang so it would be CamelExtension(context.system).context ? Anyways, I find it interesting that msg.bodyAs requires access to a camel context whereas msg.body.asInstanceOf does not :-)

Comment: It's not weird at all, it needs to check if it needs to convert to that type or not: camelContext.getTypeConverter.mandatoryConvertTo[T](clazz, body). Your solution `asInstanceOf` is error prone and will not convert if needed.

Comment: @ViktorKlang thanks for letting me know ! I did implicit val camelContext = CamelExtension(context.system).context ; self ! camelMessage.bodyAs[java.io.File]